# What's a good strategy to go about registering 2-step hotkeys?

Tags: .net, windows, com, hooks

User32.dll exposes a `RegisterHotKey` function, to register, well, hotkeys:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);
```

Using this API, we can register hotkeys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or whatever modifier+key combination we want to use, and then we can handle `WM_HOTKEY` messages to run the associated application command, and then we can use `UnregisterHotKey` to un-hook the key combination.

In Visual Studio, we have "composite", 2-step "chords" hotkeys:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> triggers *refactor / rename*
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> triggers *refactor / extract method*

I'm trying to think of a good way of doing exactly this, and I thought of several approaches:

1. Register <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> as a hotkey, then use a low-level key hook to capture (and swallow) the next keypress.
2. Register <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> as a hotkey, and then handle `WM_HOTKEY` messages by registering all possible 2nd keys for that hotkey; unregister them upon the next keypress. This has the advantage of processing everything as `WM_HOTKEY` messages.
3. Don't register *any* hotkeys. Use a low-level key hook to capture everything, and basically implement the hotkey-messaging logic manually.

What's the better approach, and why? Could I run into stability issues if I go with #2 and start continuously hooking and un-hooking stuff? Is there another way I haven't thought of? How are Visual Studio and ReSharper doing it?

Comment: You should consider Visual Studio's Ctrl+A (Select All), Ctrl+R, A (Run all Tests) and Ctrl+R, Ctrl+A (Debug all tests). In your 2nd approach, you'd need to determine how to handle the Ctrl+A depending on whether it was the first or second leg of a chord.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Visual Studio allows F12 as a shortcut key, while RegisterHotKey won't allow F12, so Visual Studio does not appear to be using RegisterHotKey.

This [approach](http://nateshoffner.com/blog/2013/10/c-global-hotkeys-via-getasynckeystate/) uses GetAsyncKeyState so it's avoiding RegisterHotKey *without* going too low-level, and it uses delegates to handle the hotkeys. It doesn't implement 2-step chords, but looking at the way it captures the modifiers, it looks like it could be expanded to handle chords.